# I want to make a simple bash script that will run one of my executables over 100 times

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a simple C program that measures the time it takes based on inputted files to analyze. It prints out the time taken in a sentence to stdout. Is there a way to have a bash script run this program with a particular input many times and pull out the time run from each iteration (from stdout) and so I can average that time over all iterations?

So I would run the original C program like so:

./test file1 file2 out.out

And after running, it would print 
"Elapsed time is xx.xx seconds" to stdout.

In particular, how would I write a shell script that would run test 100 times, on the same input files, and just average out the elapsed time for all runs?

Thank you, sorry for not clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$SECONDS
for i in {0..99}; do
   ./program file1 file2
done
end=$SECONDS
echo "scale=2;($end-$start)/100"|bc
```

I am just using `$SECONDS` (which `bash` counts up for you anyway) to find the total elapsed time without the need to run `awk`. Then at the end, I let `bc` calcuate the floating point average time in seconds to 2 decimal places (`scale=2`).

Comment: Thank you, but I made an edit to my original post, just wondering if that might affect your answer.

so a simple script like test.sh, run like "test.sh file1 file2 out.out"
for i in {0..99}; do
./test $1 $2 $3

But how would I average the time from all the iterations?

Comment: I have simplified it - please have another look.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for i in {0..99};
    /usr/bin/time test file1 file2 out.out 2>&1 >/dev/null | awk '
         {split($3, ct, "[:a-zA-Z]"); summ += ct[1]; sums += ct[2]}
     END {print summ/100.0, sums/100.0}
    '
done
```

The order of the redirection is important; you want stderr (the output of the time command) to be piped to awk when stdout goes to null. If you don't have any stdout, you can delete the `>/dev/null`. You can't use the bash `time` built-in, since it will time the entire pipe.

You can process the minute and second sums as you want, either to get a total elapsed time, an average time, etc.

Comment: Thank you! But when I tried this out, I got some syntax errors, I'll try to find my way around. Thanks though!

Comment: Use @MarkSetchell's answer to get a total time, then redirect the entire output through awk. Or, make the awk script a bit more complex by only processing lines with /elapsed/